# HTML Single Numbered List With Multiple Levels

Tags: html, list, format, nested

Currently I have a nested list that looks like this

```
<ul>
    <li>Potatoes</li>
        <ul>
            <li>Sweet Potatoes</li>
            <li>Fried Chips</li>
        </ul>
</ul>
```

And it renders like this:

1. Potatoes

   1. Sweet Potatoes
   2. Fried Chips

Is there a way to have it render items as if it was all one list with more than one level, such as:

1. Potatoes

   1.1 Sweet Potatoes

   1.2 Fried Chips

Comment: Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/PTbGc/

Comment: Thanks !! Just another quick question, is there anyway to stop the point "." from disappearing from the first line ? E.g in the top most level of the list the numbers display as 1 2 3 rather than 1. 2. 3.

Comment: Ok you need to make few changes. Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/PTbGc/165/

Comment: But if you want to add "." at the end in both list and it's sublist just add "." in the existing css like  LI:before { content: counters(item, ".") "."; counter-increment: item }

Answer (score 0):

There you go! :)

```
ol {
    counter-reset: item;
}
ol li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
ol li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".")".";
    counter-increment: item;
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: 100%;
    right: 10px; /* space between number and text */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
li li:before {
counter-increment: item;
content: counter(item) ". ";
}
```

The double 'li' is so that it does it in the second level.

Comment: This will only work if there is a set number of subpoints for each number, e.g if point 1 has 2 subpoints and point 2 has 3 supboints then it does not work